# How to install Storybook outside of a NextJS & Tailwind project

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, storybook

## Init

I have a project made with NextJS and TailwindCSS. Everything's working absolutely fine.

## The goal

I want to install storybook **next to** my NextJS project, so the structure is as follow:

```
my-project
-- next
---- src
------ ...
-- storybook
---- .storybook
------ ...
```

## The issue

Storybook runs, finds my components and my stories. **But** the styles are not applied, although they're applied on my front site.

I paid attention in the `my-project/storybook/.storybook/main.ts` file to the stories path (each stories will be next to the associated component):

```
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  ...
  stories: ["../../next/src/components/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  ...
};
```

and in the `my-project/storybook/.storybook/preview.ts` file to import properly the tailwindcss style:

```
import "../../next/src/app/globals.css";
```

but no style in storybook.
The only way to apply the styles is to import the built ones in `my-project/storybook/.storybook/preview.ts` file:

```
import "../../next/.next/static/css/app/layout.css";
```

but this is not a lasting solution.

### What solutions would you have to offer me? Thanks a lot!